# CRM Date Format In DD/MM/YY

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to display the date in date field on CRM form as "DD/MM/YY".
Language must be "U.S(English)".

Here, problem is that in mentioned above language date does not have the format like "DD/MM/YY" 
But if we change language to other language like Urdu, Korean then we can get the above mentioned date format BUT if we change the language user faces problem to access CRM.

Does anybody have any idea that how to display the date on the form in above mentioned Date-Format.

Here is the screen shot that I am facing problem to display the date format (DD/MM/YY) in CRM 13 online.

[image]

Any kind of help, will be appreciated.

Thank,
Anish

Comment: I added the screenshot to the question and modified my answer to reflect the new information. now which problems the users have? did you try to start from `English (United Kingdom)`?

Answer (score 0):

The date format is a personal setting for each CRM user. Each user can choose the date format they prefer starting from a language list.

Not all the date formats are available after a language is chosen, in your case the date format `dd/MM/yy` is not available under `English (United States)`.

***Steps to change the date format***

For CRM 2011 the option is under File -> Options -> Formats.

For CRM 2013 you need to click on the rowel beside the image user on the top right corner, select Options and then Formats.

There is also this utility to update the settings for all users programmatically:

http://crm2011usersettings.codeplex.com/

or

http://crm2011silverlight.codeplex.com/